# Determine the stability of a system without using the $\mathcal Z$-transform (described by a difference equation)

Tags: z-transform, stability

For example, let's say a causal LTI System is described by the following equation:

$$y[n] - ay[n-1] = x[n] - bx[n-1],\quad n \in Z$$

Is there a way to determine (in this case) the stability of the system without using the $\mathcal Z$-transform?

(Solving the problem using the $\mathcal Z$-transform would be a classical easy problem - verify that ROC of $H(z)$ contains the unit circle, I know how to do that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Just find the roots of the charactheristic polynomial associated with the LCCDE. Then for the **causal** system to be stable, all of those roots should be inside the unit circle; i.e., $|r_k| < 1$ where $r_k$ is the k-th root.

The characteristic polynomial for the above causal LCCDE is:
$$1 -  az^{-1}$$ and its single root is $r = a$, hence for this LCCDE to be stable you need $|a|<1$.

Comment: So... LCCDE  means using Laplace to my equation and getting H? But laplace for discrete systems isn't the same with Z-transform?

Comment: In this context LCCDE means Linear Constant Coefficient **Difference** Equation and Z-transform applies only. Laplace transform is for continuous time systems where LCDDE means linear constant coefficient **differential** equations.

Comment: So how did you determine the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @S'endou characteristic equation associated with $y[n]+a y[n-1] +b y[n-2] + c y[n-3]$ is $1 + a z^{-1} + b z^{-2} + c z^{-3}$...

Comment: I get it now. So you care only about the left hand, you ignore $x[n] - bx[n-1]$. Thanks

Comment: I will mark your answer as the correct solution because it is more detalied and more general, therefore more helpful.

Comment: @S'endou yes you ignore the right hand side unless there is pole-zero cancellation. If there is a pole zero cancellation (i.e., the same roots apper in both of the left and right polyomials) then you ignore that root from the stability analysis...

Answer (score 1):

It boils down to the same thing, with or without $\mathcal{Z}$-transform. You determine the roots of the [characteristic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation#Characteristic_equation_and_roots), which in your case is

$$\lambda=a\tag{1}$$

For stability, the magnitude of the roots of the characteristic equation must be smaller than $1$. So for your example you get the condition $|a|<1$ for stability.

Comment: happened again... :-)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What is the characteristic equation in this case and why?

Comment: @S'endou: Did you check the link in my answer? That should make it clear.